# Missing company logo in "Similar jobs" section

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I was just browsing a [job page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/141844/ios-developer-all-levels-tax-free-careem), and noticed something weird in the Similar Jobs section:

> [image]

One company there is missing its logo, even though in the [job page itself](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/126055/test-automation-engineer-m800-limited) there is a logo:

> [image]

Why is it missing in the Similar jobs list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, cache invalidation.

It struck again.... but it got defeated.

Logos in the "Similar jobs" section should now be consistent with what you can see on the job details page.

Note that the inconsistency affected only edge cases, in the vast majority of cases the logos were correct.

Thanks for you report!

Comment: Thanks! Now noticed something else, which isn't a bug on your side, but still a problem. The logo of [Teamwork.com](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/120317/senior-mobile-developers-at-teamworkcom-teamworkcom) (which appears in the similar jobs section too) is unreadable, the letters are just too small. Can you maybe contact them and ask for a better logo?

Comment: @ShadowWizard You best way to get this issue resolved is to flag the job (in the sidebar, there's a "flag" button)